# How can I pass Body Parameters to API Post operation using API Management Action in Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an azure function which works well when I call it from postman . I am trying to invoke the same from logic app as when an HTTP request is received. However, I am unable to pass raw content in the APIM as it does not give me an option for the same. It let me add only the subscription key.
My Azure APIM accepts file name, subscription key only.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Postman : (I have added Headers - Content-Type, Accept: using )

Headers:
Content-Type :
Accept:
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key

Body:
{
"name": "olaf"
}

---

Azure Logic App: (Using Peek Code);

{
"inputs": {
"method": "post",
"headers": {
"Accept": "application/json",
"Content-Type": "text/csv"
},
"pathTemplate": {
"template": "/scg-liquidTransformer-functionApp/liquidtransformer/{liquidtransformfilename}",
"parameters": {
"liquidtransformfilename": "@{encodeURIComponent('xmlsample.liquid')}"
}
},
"api": {
"id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/scg-mel-dev-arg-liquidtransformer/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/scg-liquidTransformer-functionApp-apimservice/apis/scg-liquidtransformer-functionapp"
},
"subscriptionKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
}

I need to send body {} as a parameter input in the azure function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN9nV.jpg).

Thanks,
Paul.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OvIY.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do configuration in your APIM, please refer to the steps below:

**1.** Go to your APIM, find your api and click the "**pencil**" icon.
[image]

**2.** In next page, click "**Request**" tab and click "**Add representation**" to add "application/json".
[image]

**3.** Then click "**New definition**"
[image]

**4.** Input the json sample of request body, it will generate the schema automatically in "**Payload**" box.
[image]

**5.** Click "**Save**", then go back to your logic app and add the APIM api. You can find there is a field "**name**" for you to choose.
[image]

Comment: @PaulGeorge Could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @PaulGeorge I'm sorry to bother you, but not vote up my answer, I mean [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as "accepted"(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks again.

Comment: I am wondering How can I give CSV input to the body like below ? and receive a JSON out put?  As the APIM needs a sample JSON always as an input               john doe,03/12/1975,56.8,
jane doe,17/03/1980,61.3,
siby ,03/12/1975,56.8,
paul ,03/12/1975,56.8,

Comment: Hi @PaulGeorge I'm not sure if this can be implemented. I will do some research on it later because I'm kind of busy right now. You can also create another post on Stack Overflow, someone else also may help you on it.