# How to pass CSV or XML data as Body Parameters to API Post operation using API Management Action in Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

This is in relation to the question : -

[How can I pass Body Parameters to API Post operation using API Management Action in Logic App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696387/how-can-i-pass-body-parameters-to-api-post-operation-using-api-management-action/65696594#65696594)

Now I am able to pass JSON through the body of my logic app.

I would like to pass CSV or XML data as Body Parameters to API Post operation using API Management Action in Logic App.

Currently, the APIM accepts JSON sample only.

I am able to pass CSV or XML data using postman without any issues. Please find the attached pictures for details of this issue.

Thanks,
Paul

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please have a try with add representation with "CONTENT TYPE" as `text/csv` and leave the "SAMPLE" and "DEFINITION" box empty like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhzTU.png). And then in your logic app, request the api like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOTLj.png).

Comment: I have post it below as the solution, could you please mark it as "accepted", thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, the solution is:

Add representation with "**CONTENT TYPE**" as text/csv and leave the "**SAMPLE**" and "**DEFINITION**" box empty like below screenshot:
[image]

And then in your logic app, request the api like this:
[image]